# Rails using cached application.css despite changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I have a Rails 3.1 application that uses SASS. The `application.css.scss` file looks like:

```
@import 'reset.css';
@import '960.css';
@import 'pages/master.css.scss';
```

I have a watchr script that touches `application.css.scss` whenever one of the @imported files is changed.

For a while this setup worked fine. Ever since last week (and I'm not sure why), Rails has been pulling a cached version of `application.css` for the webpages despite all my attempts at restarting the app, re-touching `application.css.scss`, etc. I've also deleted `.sass-cache` to no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't your application manifest automatically rebuild the file on its own? Your running in `development` right?

Comment: Could you check modification time of your application.css? It might be set to some future date.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. I stopped the server, executed `rm -fr tmp/cache`, and my css files were finally rebuild.

Comment: ugh, that was such a pain to debug. And it just cropped up out of nowhere. Thanks for the tip, total lifesaver.

Answer (score 8):

First, the usual cache clearing sanity checks might help. Clear browser cache. Clear server file cache (if you're in dev/test or can afford to in production) and sass-cache :

```bsh
rake tmp:cache:clear
rm -fr tmp/sass-cache #or 'compass clean' if using compass
```

If that doesn't help, maybe Rails compiled *ANOTHER* application.css elsewhere (that didn't get removed by the cache clearing)?

For example, I ran `compass watch app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` for debugging purposes and it created a public/assets/application.css file which, by virtue of it's location in public/,  *prevented* any new application.css.scss stylesheet changes from being noticed by Rails.   Once I removed it, the application again pulled from the .scss stylesheets. This is just one example of accidental overriding file creation. Try running a find on the entire application directory looking for any generated application.css files, doing this after the cache clearing to avoid those showing up in your results.

(FYI, to avoid my specific issue, I now run compass watch with --css-dir pointed at the cache to prevent my issue

```bsh
$ compass watch app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss  --css-dir tmp/cache/
```

)

Answer (score 8):

I've had a similiar issue after running `rake assets:precompile` in development. Maybe Rails is serving precompiled assets from `public/assets`? Try cleaning that up.

You shouldn't need to touch aplication.css.scss in development, rails should serve the new content whenever one of the @included files changes.

Also, make sure you have the following in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

Answer (score 7):

If you replace `@import 'file.css';` with  `@import 'file';` in your `application.scss` that should allow it to be auto-refreshed in development mode

I had been using `bin/rails tmp:clear` until I removed the file extension

Comment: This finally fixed it for me! CSS changes are now automatically picked up on page refresh after removing the file extensions from imports.

Comment: works for me also with scss instead of css! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> To wipe out the asset pipeline cache, a brute force rm -rf tmp/* will
>   suffice. This has certainly fixed a few otherwise inexplicable CSS and
>   JavaScript glitches in my experience. As a preventative measure, it
>   might also be a good idea to clear the cache after upgrading gems or
>   changing the asset pipeline configuration, although this may just be
>   superstition.
>
> Finally, if you are experimenting with rake assets:precompile in your
>   development environment (more on this in a later article), you’ll also
>   want to rm -rf public/assets/* afterwards to clean that up.

http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/02/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-1-caches-and-compass/

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke Rails *automagic* cache busting by doing the following:

1. Rename the SASS file as a partial, i.e. with an underscore prefix. E.g. `_master.css.scss`
2. Remove the extension from the import. You can keep the paths, but exclude the underscore. E.g. `@import 'pages/master';`

Now you can make changes in master and have them reflected without messing with the cache manually.

(Note: I'm on Rails 4.2)

Comment: OMG this is the answer I've been looking for for 6 hours! It must be some type of miracle that you answered 14 days before me on a 9 year old question! (Rails 5.0)

Comment: Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Rails 6.0.3.1 today. I had to re-touch `application.scss` so that rails didn't use the cached version.

Running `rake tmp:cache:clear` helped, but it's annoying because I had to run the command every time I updated any partial scss file. :(

Answer (score -1):

Random I was having a caching issue related to using twitter bootstrap and application.css.scss. Basically I changed application.css.scss to just plain application.css and fixed my problem. Maybe this can help you? If you haven't figured it out already.

Comment: Won't work if you have variables or Sass in your `application.scss`!

Answer (score -1):

I was having this problem, but I was actually putting css into application.css, rather than into files that it included.  I cleared out application.css to simply include all of my css.  So, my application.css now looks like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require 'bootstrap.min'
 *= require 'global'
 */
```

My changes are reflected any time I change one of the included files (e.g. global.css)