# Rails asset pipeline version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using Zurb Foundation to build a Rails project.  I installed it using the foundation-rails gem.  I was running 5.2.0.0 and recently updated to version 5.3.1.0 of the gem, and my Gemfile reflects that:

```
foundation-rails (5.3.1.0)
  railties (>= 3.1.0)
  sass (>= 3.2.0)
```

I recently noticed a difference between the CSS in dev and production.  On inspection, I noticed that my dev version was referencing this file:

```
/* line 74, /Users/andrew/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/foundation-rails-5.2.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/components/_side-nav.scss */
```

So my dev environment is still referencing an old version of the CSS file, even though the Gemfile.lock file shows that I'm using the most current version of the gem.  I tried restarting my server - no change.

My gem version list shows this:

```
foundation-rails (5.3.1.0, 5.3.0.1, 5.2.0.0)
```

So I uninstall version 5.2.0.0, and my dev environment starts working as expected.

Why was Rails referencing an old version of the CSS file when the Gemfile clearly shows that it's using the most recent version of the gem?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the sass cache? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11248821/697745

Comment: I didn't, and I can't reproduce the issue now that I've fixed it.  I'll try that if it pops up again.

Comment: Yeah, my question was more for my own education rather than needing a fix.  The asset pipeline is still a little black magic to me.