# Rails Puma: --no-dev-caching does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, windows-8.1

Whenever I change an included `.scss` file I cannot see the changes, even if I restart the server. I found that if I manually delete `tmp/cache/*` then restart the server, I can see the changes one time. Further changes are not shown (and the cache is back). I have tried `rails server --no-dev-caching` but it doesn't help. I have

```
config.assets.digest = false
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.quiet = false
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store
```

**How can I see changes to my SCSS files when I reload the page in development?** I test with `curl http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css | less` and search for the class that I changed and saved.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
* Version 3.12.2 (ruby 2.4.3-p205), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Environment: development
```

Docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/configuring.html#configuring-assets

---

I commented out Puma, used WebBrick with `rails server --no-dev-caching`, set `config.assets.debug = true`, loaded `$ curl http://localhost:3000/assets/theme/theme.self.css | less`, and the change was *still* not there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here! https://stackoverflow.com/a/59895954/148844

I had to change `@import "theme-overrides.scss";` => `@import "theme-overrides";`, rename `theme-overrides.scss` => `_theme-overrides.scss`, change `@import "theme_components/helpers.scss";` => `@import "theme_components/helpers";`, rename `helpers.scss` => `_helpers.scss`, and it all worked!

Now I have to rename 100 different files!